# How do I make this sentence sound right?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Alan Bradley used many events and moments to show **the protagonist's, Flavia’s,** development and precocious personality in his novel, The Sweetness at the Bottom of the Pie.

Is it ok if I put this:

Alan Bradley used many events and moments to show **the protagonist, Flavia’s** development and precocious personality in his novel, The Sweetness at the Bottom of the Pie.

Comment: I'm not sure how clear the answers are on that earlier question, but to my mind it's relevant that *in principle* the comma before the [appositive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm) (***Flavia***, here) can be discarded (maybe thereby making the preceding term an "attributive" noun). From which perspective it should be pretty obvious you don't want possessive apostrophes on *both*, but in practice I'm sure lots of people would be tempted to include it twice.

Comment: the development of the protagonist, Flavia,etc. ///the least awkward